# How do I do forms authentication to my own database's tables?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

In my MSSQL database I've created two tables:

- users
- userroles

User has a col named userrole that FK to the table.

Now, I just opened VS 2010 and created a MVC 3 w/Forms Authentication as I'm going to create a  community site that allows users to register and login.

But I thought there was a way I can modify the FormsAuthentication to use my tables to check/get the necessary data or am I mistaken? I don't see a database connection anywhere, so is the forms auth thingy living its own life in my application, just handling the auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do auth MS's way but with your own tables you have to implement your own Membership Provider

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{ 
// go on overriding members
}
```